# VS code snippet transfrom

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

The filename is currently `filename.dto.ts`

I'm trying to transform `filename.dto.ts` to `FilenameInput` or `FilenameOutput`

However, it seems this is not a way to select the second group using regex.

How can I properly select the second regex group and transform it?

```js
export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)|(.dto)$/${1:/upcase}$2/}Input {}
export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.dto)//}Output {}`
```

Comment: what is the use of the `|`? Don't you need to escape the `.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^([^.]*).*/${1:/pascalcase}$2/}Input {}"`

Your first capture group is everything up to the first `.`.

Then you need to match everything else `.*` will match `.dto` (and don't replace it with anything since you don't want it in your result).

You do not need a second capture group but the previous version I showed did have a capture group 2 (but it wasn't transformed) and it looked like:

`export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([^.]*).*/${1:/upcase}$2/}Input {}`

Comment: So, for example if filename is "filename". Then, ^(.) => "f"  -> this becomes uppercased, and the second group, ([^.]*) => $2/  Does this mean "do not transform"? and the Third group .* is transformed to nothing? I'm not quite getting how this works.

Comment: Yes, you are just replacing the "match" with an untransformed $2.  The remainder, isn't a group, but it needs to be part of the match - you will be replacing the match, so if you didn't have that remainder part in there the rest of the filename would just pass through untouched into the result.  So that remainder isn't really transformed into anything, it is just matched and ignored so you don't see it again.

Comment: I simplified the transform so there isn't any need for a capture group 2 anymore thanks to the undocumented pascalcase conversion.